# How to create multiple plots in one graph using two csv files with pandas and matplotlib?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have gone through a lot of questions similar to this, but could not come across one that would suit my problem. I have 2 different data in 2 different csv files and I want to summon them in the code to plot both of them in one graph. I have tried this code below, and occasionally made several variations:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df1 = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\HP\OneDrive\Desktop\MPGES-1\Computational_work\MD\furazan1224\paralel\25_50\0_75\gsh\rmsd_gsh.csv", sep=";")
df2 = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\HP\OneDrive\Desktop\MAKALE\in_prep\MAO\revizyon\yeni_MD\a-mao\rmsd_15.csv", sep=";")

a = df1.plot(kind="line", color="red", title="rmsd", xlabel="Time", ylabel="rmsd", x=0, y=1)
b = df2.plot(kind="line", color="blue", title="rmsd", xlabel="Time", ylabel="rmsd", x=0, y=1)

plt.show()
```

I feel like it's very close once it's possible to somehow merge a with b. However, couldn't find an acceptable function to do this.

Thanks,

Comment: Samples of both csvs as well as some type of explanation of what the resulting graph should look like would be helpful.

Comment: `df2.plot(..., ax=a)`?

Comment: @BigBen it worked :) didn't expect such quick solution 